# Delay when binding request.POST data to form in django

Tags: django, django-views

I'm getting unexplainable delay of about 20.-30 seconds when trying to bind request.POST data to form:

```
    CompanyFormset = modelformset_factory(Company, form=EditCompanyForm, extra=0)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = CompanyFormset(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
```

It only happens on one server, no matter if I use development server or mod_wsgi. When trying on my development computer everything works fast enough. If I try to save model by manually assigning values it's fast as it should be.

Delay only happens on this line:

```
formset = CompanyFormset(request.POST)
```

..and I have no more ideas what can cause it or where to look for problem cause.

Any suggestions what to do?

Here is the model too:

```
class Company(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(_('name'),blank=True, max_length=200)
type_of_corporation = models.CharField(_('type of organization'),blank=True, max_length=100)
tax_number = models.CharField(_('tax number'),blank=True, max_length=100)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
logo = models.FileField(_('logo'),upload_to='bex/logos', blank=True, null=True)
description = models.TextField(_('description'),blank=True)
street = models.CharField(_('street'),blank=True, max_length=100)
city = models.CharField(_('city'),blank=True, max_length=100)
zip = models.CharField(_('zip'),blank=True, max_length=50)
region = models.CharField(_('region'),blank=True, max_length=100)
COUNTRIES = (
    ('Croatia', 'Croatia'),
    ('Slovenia', 'Slovenia'),
)
country = models.CharField(_('country'),max_length=20, choices=COUNTRIES)
telephone = models.CharField(_('telephone'),blank=True, max_length=20)
fax = models.CharField(_('fax'),blank=True, max_length=20)
email = models.EmailField(_('email'),blank=True)
website = models.URLField(_('website'),null=True, blank=True, verify_exists=False)
representing_person = models.CharField(_('representing person'), blank=True, max_length=100)
owner = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_('owner'), related_name='company_owner')
owner_approved = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
company_approved = models.BooleanField(default=True)
business_category = models.ForeignKey(BusinessCategory, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_('business category'))
subscription_date = models.DateTimeField(_('subscription date'),blank=True, null=True)
score = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
votes = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

""" company data needs to have ratings, comments, category and business tags """

class Admin:
    list_display = ('',)
    search_fields = ('',)
    save_as = True

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('Company')
    verbose_name_plural = _('Companies')


def rating_allowed(self):

    if not self.subscription_date:
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(id=self.owner.id)
            if (datetime.today() - user.date_joined).days < 30:
                rating_allowed = True
        except:
            rating_allowed = False
    else:
        if (datetime.today() - self.subscription_date).days < 365:
            rating_allowed = True
        else:
            rating_allowed = False
    self.rating_allowed = rating_allowed
    return self.rating_allowed

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/companies/%i/" % self.id

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: Post Company model too please

Comment: Here, added it to the post above.

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks okay in the model. You could try the excellent [django debug toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar) which reports timings, and may help you pinpoint what it's taking so long.

Comment: Tried it, and tried with pdb. Queries take the same amount of time on my development laptop, and on server. When going step by step with pdb is stalls on the line I mentioned above, everything looks frozen for aboy 20-30 seconds and then continues as it should. If I put the values through the pdb manually, then validate and save the model, it saves fast. Maybe the cause of the problem is outside django, but I cannot imagine what could it be.